# Find average salary of a department using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How do I find the average salary for each department?

```
 var employees = new List<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee {Name = "Tom", Age = 32,Department = "Design",Salary=120000},
                    new Employee {Name = "John", Age = 22,Department = "UI",Salary=86000},
                    new Employee {Name = "Sandra", Age = 36,Department = "UI",Salary=83000},
                    new Employee {Name = "Julie", Age = 54,Department = "Javascript",Salary=80000},
                    new Employee {Name = "Samantha", Age = 21,Department = "Design",Salary=125000}
                };

var massagedEmployees = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department).Select(g=>g.??????
```

In SQL I would do something like

```
select Department,avg(salary) from Employees group by Department
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
var massagedEmployees = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department)
                                .Select(g => new { Department = g.Key, Avg = g.Average(e => e.Salary) } );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var massagedEmployees = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department)
                                 .Select(g=>g.Average(x=>x.Salary));
```

You should include the `Department key` like this:

```
var massagedEmployees = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department)
                                 .Select(g=> 
                                   new {
                                      Department = g.Key,
                                      SalaryAvg = g.Average(x=>x.Salary)
                                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var massagedEmployees = employees
                       .GroupBy(e => e.Department)
                       .Select(p=> new {p.Key, p.Average(q=>q.Salary)};
```

Comment: @ReedCopsey Opps. Thanks.Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
employees.Where(e => e.Department == "[department]")
         .Average(e => e.Salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var massagedEmployees =
                employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department).Select(c => new {Dep = c.Key, Sum = c.Sum(i => i.Salary)/c.Count()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can simplify it to a single operator unlike the previous GroupBy answers GroupBy has an overload just for that so that you don't need the following select:

```
employees.GroupBy(e=>e.Department,items=>items.Average(e=>e.Salary))
```